# how can I iterate through this json document using ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, elasticsearch

I have a ruby code block, as follows:

```
require "elasticsearch"
require "json"

search_term = "big data"
city = "Hong Kong"
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
r = client.search index: 'candidates', body:
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          match: {
            tags: search_term
          }
        },
        {
          match: {
            city: city
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It produces multiple returns like this one:

```
{"_index":"candidates","_type":"data",
"_id":"AU3DyAmvtewNSFHuYn88",
"_score":3.889237,
"_source":{"first":"Kota","last":"Okayama","city":"Tokyo","designation":"Systems Engineer","email":"user@hotmail.co.jp","phone":"phone","country":"Japan","industry":"Technology","tags":["remarks","virtualization big data"]}}
```

I want to iterate through it and extract various elements. I have tried

```
 data = JSON.parse(r)
  data.each do |row|
  puts row["_source"]["first"]
 end
```

and the error is:

```
no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)
```

What's the best way forward on this chaps?

Comment: Just try to include complete string into single quote try below code in irb h='{"_index":"candidates","_type":"data",
"_id":"AU3DyAmvtewNSFHuYn88",
"_score":3.889237,
"_source":{"first":"Kota","last":"Okayama","city":"Tokyo","designation":"Systems Engineer","email":"user@hotmail.co.jp","phone":"phone","country":"Japan","industry":"Technology","tags":["remarks","virtualization big data"]}}'

then you can access values h["country"]

Comment: thank you, that returns multiple errors.  I want to be able to extract elements both to print them as HTML and also to use the email address to send broadcast emails

Comment: Can you please check if you have missed out some thing because I have just pasted it from my console after trying it

Comment: thank you, please note that the object is produced by the ruby code at the top of this question (the json example is just  part of the return). If I put single quotes before the first { and after the last } in the ruby code block it does not work. I just get an error message.

Comment: I tried just with the json string (not the full ruby code) and h["city"] returns city not Tokyo and h{"_source"]["city"] returns nothing

Comment: Can you try using the code I.have added

Comment: where is the code you mean? The stuff at the top? I have tired that unless you have added something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79871/discussion-between-user1903663-and-anant-kolvankar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution, I hope it helps somebody else. It took me hours of fiddling and experimentation. Here it is:

```
require "elasticsearch"
require "json"

search_term = "big data"
city = "Tokyo"
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true

h = client.search index: 'swiss_candidates', body:
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          match: {
            tags: search_term
          }
        },
        {
          match: {
            city: city
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
} 

data = JSON.parse(h.to_json) 
data["hits"]["hits"].each do |r|
puts r["_id"]
puts r["_source"]["first"]
puts r["_source"]["tags"][1]
puts r["_source"]["screened"][0]
end
```

The important thing seems to be to convert the elasticsearch result into something ruby friendly.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` expects a `String` containing a JSON document, but you are passing it the `Hash` which was returned from `client.search`.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with that, why you want to parse something which is already a Ruby `Hash` into a Ruby `Hash`.

Comment: thank you. I want to be able to extract each email address from the hash, for example to send a mail through mandrill. How would I isolate the email address? @email = r["_source"]["email"] for example?

Comment: Thank you, if that is the case as above, how can I access the hash as is to iterate through the elements?